# How can I convert float array to GLfloat array?

Tags: c

How can I convert float array to Glfloat array?
I need to make Graph and I need to send array of floats to display Function.
my float array is global Variable/

Comment: GLfloat:  typedef float GLfloat;  No need to convert

Comment: What have you tried so far? Please provide some code so we can help you understand why it's not working for you.

Comment: for (i=0;i<20;i++)
 for (j=0;j<1;j++){
  glColor3f(0.0, 0.4, 0.0);
    glBegin(GL_LINE_STRIP);
      glVertex2f(marr[i][j],marr[i][j+1]);
 }

 glFlush();
marr[20][2] is a globale  that Contains points and i need to make a graph with this points.

Answer (score 1):

`GLfloat` is a typedef for `float`. You don't need to convert between the two.

Comment: the program not let me use this array inside of display Function.error C2440: '=' : cannot convert from 'float *(*)[2]' to 'GLfloat'

Comment: You should post code, but it looks like you are passing an array of floats when it just simply wants a single float.

Comment: i mean openGL display.